# Iperf3 - Specify different TX/RX throughputs for a bidirectional test

Tags: iperf3

Hello Dear Engineers :)

I was trying to run the following test using iperf3:

> `iperf3 --bidir -u -c 10.100.254.14 -i 10 -b 60m -t 86400`

Due to the current nature of the system I'm testing, the TX and RX throughputs are different for the bidirectional test.
Is there a specific way, as to specify a different throughput for TX and RX in the iperf3 command provided above?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

iperf3 doesn't support separate target bitrates (`-b`) for Tx and Rx in bidirectional mode.

If you need bidirectional testing you can run two instances of iperf3, one for Tx (by default) and one Rx (`-R`). If separate shells don't work for you, the most practical way might be to start both instances from a batch script and redirect their respective output to separate log files.